# Looking for perfect Logic

Tags: php, arrays

I'm working on `foreach` loop to loop all the images according to below html design $galleryImage must have a minimum of 4 images and class="container" contains only the first 4 images and div hidden-gal first 4 images will go 1 by 1 in each container_rm and remaining in the same manner. This what I want to achieve

```
 <?php 
    $galleryImage = array(
        '1' => 'image1.jpg',
        '2' => 'image2.jpg',
        '3' => 'image3.jpg',
        '4' => 'image4.jpg',
        '5' => 'image5.jpg',
        '6' => 'image6.jpg',
        '7' => 'image7.jpg',
        '8' => 'image8.jpg',
        '9' => 'image9.jpg',
        '10' => 'image10.jpg',
        '11' => 'image11.jpg',
        '12' => 'image12.jpg',
        '13' => 'image13.jpg',
        '14' => 'image14.jpg',
        '15' => 'image15.jpg',
        '16' => 'image16.jpg',
    );
?>
<div class="container">
    <ul><li><img src="image1.jpg" alt=""></li></ul>
    <ul><li><img src="image2.jpg" alt=""></li></ul>
    <ul><li><img src="image3.jpg" alt=""></li></ul>
    <ul><li><img src="image4.jpg" alt=""></li></ul>
</div>
<div class="hidden-gal">
    <div class="container_rm1">
        <img src="image1.jpg" alt="">
        <img src="image5.jpg" alt="">
        <img src="image6.jpg" alt="">
        <img src="image7.jpg" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="container_rm2">
        <img src="image2.jpg" alt="">
        <img src="image8.jpg" lt="">
        <img src="image9.jpg" alt="">
        <img src="image10.jpg" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="container_rm3">
        <img src="image3.jpg" alt="">
        <img src="image11.jpg" alt="">
        <img src="image12.jpg" alt="">
        <img src="image13.jpg" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="container_rm1">
        <img src="image4.jpg" alt="">
        <img src="image14.jpg" alt="">
        <img src="image15.jpg" alt="">
        <img src="image16.jpg" alt="">
    </div>
</div>
```

This how I'm doing:

```
<div class="container">    
<?php
    $j = 1;
    foreach($galleryImage as $i){
        // echo $j;
        if($j == 1){
            $da_ro = '-15';
        }elseif($j == 2){
            $da_ro = '-5';
        }elseif($j == 3){
            $da_ro = '5';
        }elseif($j == 4){
            $da_ro = '15';
        }else{
            $da_ro = '5';
        }
        echo '<li data-images="container_'.$j.'" data-rotation="'.$da_ro.'"><img src="'. $i . '"/></li>';   
        $j++;                 
    }
?>
</div>
```

I don't get the other part means I can create the loop using the foreach and then add if and else but I need more robust solution because `$galleryImage` may contain less images.

Comment: So what is the logic here? How many images should go to first block?

Comment: $galleryImage must have a minimum of 4 images and class="container" contains only the first 4 images and div hidden-gal first 4 images will go 1 by 1 in each container_rm and remaining in the same manner

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basic code to start with:

```
$galleryImage = array(
    '1' => 'image1.jpg',
    '2' => 'image2.jpg',
    '3' => 'image3.jpg',
    '4' => 'image4.jpg',
    '5' => 'image5.jpg',
    '6' => 'image6.jpg',
    '7' => 'image7.jpg',
    '8' => 'image8.jpg',
    '9' => 'image9.jpg',
    '10' => 'image10.jpg',
    '11' => 'image11.jpg',
    '12' => 'image12.jpg',
    '13' => 'image13.jpg',
    '14' => 'image14.jpg',
    '15' => 'image15.jpg',
    '16' => 'image16.jpg',
);

$size = 4;
$firstItems = array_splice($galleryImage, 0, $size);
//print_r($firstItems);

$chunkSize = ceil(count($galleryImage) / $size);
$groupedItems = array_chunk($galleryImage, $chunkSize);
//print_r($groupedItems);

foreach ($firstItems as $key => $value) {
    echo $value . '<br />';
    foreach ($groupedItems[$key] ?? [] as $item) {
        echo $item . '<br />';
    }
     echo '<br /><br />';
}
```

Fiddle [here](https://3v4l.org/HEc1R).

Answer (score 0):

You can use this method like below:

```
foreach ($galleryImage as $key => $value) {
    echo 'key=>'.$key.'and value=>'.$value;
    // like this
    if($key =='1'){
        echo $value;
    }
}
```